# Erlang custom httpd module - how to send custom HTTP headers and Content-Type

Tags: erlang, inets

I'm implementing a custom module for Erlang's httpd (inets) server. I can successfully respond with HTML content with the following implementation of `do` method:

```
do(_ModData) ->
    Body = "<html><body>Hello world</body></html>",
    {proceed, [{response, {200, Body}}]}.
```

but the problem is I cannot find a way to respond with custom headers and `text/xml` content type.

According to erlang httpd docs, I can respond with `[{response,{response,Head,Body}}]`, where "Head is a key value list of HTTP header fields" (quote from the docs), but what should be the exact format of this list? I tried the following, but it gives 404:

```
do(_ModData) ->
    Body = "<html><body>Stats Placeholder</body></html>",
    Head = ["Content-Length", "40", "Content-Type", "text/html"],
    {proceed, [{response, {response, Head, Body}}]}.
```

Any help on this would be appreciated, the docs and examples for erlang httpd are really sparse...

Answer (score 1):

Try `[{content_length, "40"}, {content_type, "text/html"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Try [{"Content-Length", "40"}, {"Content-Type", "text/html"}]

Answer (score 0):

LOL. Is in the doc.

```
[{code, 200}, {content_length, "40"}, {content_type, "text/html"}]
```